# How do I pick a random Clifford operation in Stim?

Tags: programming, randomised-benchmarking, shadow-tomography, stim

I want to sample random n-qubit Clifford operations. How do I do that in Stim?

(Self-answering because this [was requested when the feature already existed](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/issues/153))

Answer (score 2):

The method `stim.Tableau.random(n)` generates a uniformly random n-qubit Clifford operation, using the algorithm from ["Hadamard-free circuits expose the structure of the Clifford group"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.09412), and returns its stabilizer tableau.

**example**

```
import stim
t = stim.Tableau.random(10)
print(repr(t))
```

**sample output**

```
stim.Tableau.from_conjugated_generators(
    xs=[
        stim.PauliString("-ZZXZZY__YX"),
        stim.PauliString("-___XXXZZZ_"),
        stim.PauliString("+YXZY_Y_Z__"),
        stim.PauliString("-YZYXXXY_YY"),
        stim.PauliString("+YZXZYXZ__Y"),
        stim.PauliString("+ZZZXZYYY__"),
        stim.PauliString("-_YZ___ZYXY"),
        stim.PauliString("+_YXYZXYY_Y"),
        stim.PauliString("-Y__YZ_____"),
        stim.PauliString("+ZZXZ_Z_XYY"),
    ],
    zs=[
        stim.PauliString("+_YZXXZZYZZ"),
        stim.PauliString("-YXZXYXY_XY"),
        stim.PauliString("-_YXXXZYYYX"),
        stim.PauliString("+_YYZYZ_ZYX"),
        stim.PauliString("-_XY___YYZY"),
        stim.PauliString("-ZX_ZZYZ_YY"),
        stim.PauliString("-_Y_XXXZYXZ"),
        stim.PauliString("-Y__ZYXY_XX"),
        stim.PauliString("-Y_X_YZXZYY"),
        stim.PauliString("+Y__ZXZY_XX"),
    ],
)
```

**performance**

This method has asymptotic cubic scaling (eg. it performs a schoolbook matrix multiplication).

```
>>> %time t = stim.Tableau.random(10)
Wall time: 253 µs

>>> %time t = stim.Tableau.random(100)
Wall time: 11.3 ms

>>> %time t = stim.Tableau.random(1000)
Wall time: 289 ms

>>> %time t = stim.Tableau.random(10000)
Wall time: 2min 20s
```

Comment: can stim generate random errors from depolarizing channel? for example error=stim.DepolarizingChannel(100,0.1) . (100 qubits,p=0.1; I asked this question a few days ago)

Comment: @unknown stim has circuit instructions for single qubit depolarization and two qubit depolarization. But it doesn't return them it just applies them while simulating.

Comment: this might still work. I want to simulate the performance of codes in depolarizing channel. Codes are usually CSS but sometimes more general stabilizer codes. The number of qubits is large (50-1000). Is stim suitable for this sort of simulations? if it is are there examples with performance curves and runtimes?

Comment: @unknown Stim will deal with that easily. It can sample full shots from 10K qubit circuits with 10M operations at 1KHz, after a 15s analysis delay. Watch Part 2 of this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3NaTGmY0Rw

Comment: great...you've convinced me to install it.